# Error while running beam streaming pipeline (Python) with pub/sub io in embedded Flinkrunner (apache_beam [GCP])

Tags: python, apache-beam, flink-streaming, google-cloud-pubsub

I am facing the following error while running a streaming pipeline (python) in Apache Beam on Flinkrunner. The pipeline contains a GCP pub/sub io source and pub/sub target.

```
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.6 interpreter.

ERROR:root:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PCollectionNodes [PCollectionNode{id=ref_PCollection_PCollection_1, PCollection=unique_name: "23 Read from Pub/Sub/Read.None"
coder_id: "ref_Coder_BytesCoder_1"
is_bounded: UNBOUNDED
windowing_strategy_id: "ref_Windowing_Windowing_1"
}] were consumed but never produced
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/pipeline.py", line 586, in __exit__
    self.result.wait_until_finish()
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/portability/portable_runner.py", line 599, in wait_until_finish
    raise self._runtime_exception
RuntimeError: Pipeline BeamApp-swarna0kpaul-0712135603-763999c_45da372e-757d-4690-8e25-1a5ed0a5cc84 failed in state FAILED: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: PCollectionNodes [PCollectionNode{id=ref_PCollection_PCollection_1, PCollection=unique_name: "23 Read from Pub/Sub/Read.None"
coder_id: "ref_Coder_BytesCoder_1"
is_bounded: UNBOUNDED
windowing_strategy_id: "ref_Windowing_Windowing_1"
}] were consumed but never produced
```

I am trying to run the following code in Python
I am trying to run using 2 pub/sub topics I created in my GCP account ({input topic},{output topic})
The topics are in this format - projects/{project name}/topics/{topic name}

```
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
input_topic=<input topic>
output_topic=<output topic>
options = PipelineOptions(["--runner=FlinkRunner", "--checkpointing_interval=1000","--streaming"])
with beam.Pipeline(options=options ) as pipeline:
  input1 = pipeline | " Read from Pub/Sub" >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(topic=input_topic).with_output_types(bytes)
  output = (input1
            |beam.WindowInto(beam.transforms.window.FixedWindows(5))
            |"Write to Pub/Sub" >>beam.io.WriteToPubSub(topic=output_topic, with_attributes=False).with_input_types(bytes))
```

The following versions of the software are available in the system

```
Python 3.6.8
apache_beam [gcp]==2.30.0
java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)
```

I tried running this with flink cluster and portable flink runner as per specification in [this](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/flink/) page, but got the same error.

The same code is running fine when I used the following options

```
options = PipelineOptions(["--streaming"])
```

Comment: Is it possible to provide full code? Also could you provide all steps you've done?

Comment: I apologize there was some error in the earlier code.
I have updated the code I am trying to run using 2 pub/sub topics I created in my GCP account (<input topic>,<output topic>)
The topics are in this format - projects/<project name>/topics/<topic name>
Here is the list of steps I performed

- created a centos 8 GCP compute instance
- Installed java
- Installed following python libraries
Cython
apache_beam [gcp]==2.31.0
google-cloud-pubsub==1.7.0
grpcio==1.34.1
pandas
flask
flask_cors
psycopg2

- Ran the above code

Comment: So if I good understand, when you changed `options = PipelineOptions(["--runner=FlinkRunner", "--checkpointing_interval=1000","--streaming"])` to `options = PipelineOptions(["--streaming"])` it worked fine? If so, please provide answer with this solution which might be useful for other users. If you still have issue please provide more details.

Comment: Running with ```options = PipelineOptions(["--streaming"])``` is working fine. But I am still facing the same issues with FlinkRunner as mentioned above and I want to make it run with the FlinkRunner as the end goal is to run it in Flink cluster

Comment: where you able to solve this issue? we're having trouble running FlinkRunner locally with a pubsub emulator.

Comment: To clarify @PjoterS DirectRunner works just fine. It is only in FlinkRunner mode that has issues.

Comment: @eddiewang not yet! Earlier I tried running in a flink cluster but same issue there also.

Comment: how did u eventually solve it? i encountered exactly same error with SparkRunner: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72152450/apache-beam-io-readfrompubsubtopic-input-topic-doesnt-work-with-sparkrunner

Comment: Not able to solve it yet. ☹️

Comment: Did this work for anyone?

Answer (score 1):

The `apache_beam.io.ReadFromPubsub()` transform only works with DirectRunner and Dataflow Runner, but there is an external transform you can try: `apache_beam.io.external.gcp.pubsub.ReadFromPubSub`, see: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/release-2.39.0/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/external/gcp/pubsub.py#L39